# How can I print out the first line of a matcher?

Tags: java, android

So I'm having problems with my code. Currently, the matcher in this function I have returns 3 lines instead of 1 line. I want it to return only the first line that it has found. Here's my function:

```
private void getLibraryMap(String libraryName) {
        File file = new File("/proc/self/maps");
        if (file.exists()) {
            try {
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/self/maps"));
                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    if (line.contains(libraryName)) {
                        String lines = line.replace(String.valueOf(Pattern.compile("\\s+")), " ");
                        Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\p{XDigit}+");
                        Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(lines).region(0, 8);
                        while (matcher.find()) {
                            long startAddress = Long.parseLong(matcher.group(0));
                            Log.e("MainActivity", String.valueOf(startAddress));
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is how I invoke it:

```
getLibraryMap("libwebviewchromium_loader.so");
```

This is the log I get from it:

```
E/MainActivity: 96862000
    96864000
E/MainActivity: 96865000
```

Can anybody help me solve this problem? Many thanks :)

Comment: Use `if (matcher.find())` instead of while so you will get only the first match. correct me if I misunderstood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
while (matcher.find()) {
     long startAddress = Long.parseLong(matcher.group(0));
     Log.e("MainActivity", String.valueOf(startAddress));
     }
```

to

```
if (matcher.find()) {
 long startAddress = Long.parseLong(matcher.group(0));
 Log.e("MainActivity", String.valueOf(startAddress));
 }
```

**while** means it will loop till the condition is true

**if** here will execute only once as soon as it finds the first match